# Storing array as list doesn't work

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-odm, odm

I'm trying to insert an array in my mongo collection like this

`field:[tag1,tag2,tag3]`

my mapping is

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Hash
 */
protected $field=array();
```

I'm inserting like this in PHP :

```
$message->setField([$idme,$to]);
```

While I want it stored as list, I get this format:

```
 "field" : {
                "0" : "533f28c9211b6f7e448b4567",
                "1" : "52cb29b0211b6fd9248b456b"
        }
```

How can I achieve my goal ?

Comment: @jmikola can you look at this ?

Comment: Are you sure this is what is getting stored? Can you test it with mongo client and see the result?

Comment: Yes , I should have used Collection instead of Hash, now it works great

Comment: aahh... okay ..! Great.